# Msiexec REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vamus is not working

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In my installer (created using WiX) I forcefully re install everything using msiexec REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vamus /qr /i setup.msi command. This was working fine but after adding a new component (an exe file) it stopped working. nw if I try this command it doesn't replaces the file in installation directory.

To solve this I tried adding the new file as a part of an existing component but that didn't work.

Any idea/solution to solve this? 
Does MSI check for all the existing files (installed by previous package) and fail if it doesn't find one of the file when I use the above command?

Comment: Did you increment ProductVersion when you added the component? Small updates aren't easy to reason about; try to get at least to a Minor Upgrade scenario.

Comment: First of all take a look at verbose log to know for sure what Windows Installer is doing

Comment: Check out: [http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/1/4/Doing-a-small-update-or-minor-upgrade-in-MSI-Use](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/1/4/Doing-a-small-update-or-minor-upgrade-in-MSI-Use). Almost certainly that is your problem.